# Would it be good if I use flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Would it be good if I use flexbox for my new site as I want my site to be compatible with older version of browsers as well? What should I do for the older browser issues?

Comment: Maybe you should try it first..

Comment: I want to learn it in depth by applying it practically

Answer (score 3):

Check [Can I Use Flex Box](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
 to see the versions of browsers that can work with flexes, and if you need older browsers to be supported you can check this polyfill
[A JavaScript polyfill for Flexbox](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility)

Comment: Thnx Alexandr, will give it a try and will let u know

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: No.

**Long Answer**: Although the `Flexbox` is a great tool, until this day (6-Sep-2016) it still has different issues with different browsers (modern browsers). Can you get it to work in most of the modern/updated browsers? Most likely, yes. Can you do some workarounds to make it work for older browsers? Maybe, but that will be such a hell of a task, absolutely not worth the effort.

**Bottom Line**: Use something else. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is good for starters.